# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ban')

Tags: discord.js

```js
client.on("channelCreate", async function(channel) {
  const logs = await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ limit: 1, type: 'CHANNEL_CREATE' });
  const log = logs.entries.first();
  if (!log) return;
  const kanal = channel.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'ticket')
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Protection System")
      .setDescription(`ο/η ${log.executor} έγινε banned επειδή έκανε αρκετά κανάλια`)
      .setColor("RED")
  const get = db.get(`channel2_${log.executor.id}`)
  if(get === true)return channel.delete(),kanal.send({embeds: [embed]}),logs.executor.ban('Protection : Channel Created')
});
```

When I run this code, it returns this error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ban')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, the `logs` variable refers to [`GuildAuditLogs`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildAuditLogs) which is the collection of audit logs. It doesn't have an `executor` property. Instead, what you are looking for is the `log` variable (without an 's'). It contains the [`executor`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=executor) property. But using the `executor` property gives you an [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/User) object, so it still wouldn't have an `.ban()` property. So you would have to fetch the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember) who did the action. So, your fixed code would look like this:

```js
client.on("channelCreate", async function(channel) {
  const logs = await channel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ limit: 1, type: 'CHANNEL_CREATE' });
  const log = logs.entries.first();
  const logExecutorMember = await channel.guild.members.fetch(log.executor.id)
  if (!log) return;
  const kanal = channel.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'ticket')
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Protection System")
      .setDescription(`ο/η ${log.executor} έγινε banned επειδή έκανε αρκετά κανάλια`)
      .setColor("RED")
  const get = db.get(`channel2_${log.executor.id}`)
  if(get === true)return channel.delete(),kanal.send({embeds: [embed]}),logExecutorMember.ban('Protection : Channel Created')
});
```